# jquery load(url); isn't working loading content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm totally new to jquery and i'm trying to load content from a different file into a div, fading out the current content and showing the other file infor, but it doesn´t seem to work, what am i doing wrong ? its a very simple code, please help, the current content fades out but after that nothing happens.

```
$('button').click(function(){ 
    $(innerElements).fadeOut('slow'); 
    $('article').load('example.html'); 
});
```

Comment: Can you post your codes too?

Comment: `innerElements` should be `class` or `id` or should be initialized before.

Comment: Have you verified your example.html is at correct location ?

Comment: what is `innerElements`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `callback`:

```
$('button').click(function(){ 
    $('article').load('example.html', function() { 
        $(innerElements).fadeOut('slow'); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: -the load function works with php files also ? 
-is this correct ? $(el).fadeIn(750).load('url'callback); ?

Comment: Is there a code to find out if an animation has FINISHED ? I've been searching and found  the `is.(':animated')`  but this doesn't seem to return true if animation has come to an end,  it returns true when it starts the animation. eg.  `if($.is(':animated')){alert('')}` this alert shows  right before the animation starts, i know that with a `callback`  it would show the alert after but it isn't what I need, in other words I want to animate other elements but depending on which animation is finished the other will start.